# Linked Server failing on SQL Server job

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs, linked-server

I have a linked server that perfectly works when executing a query. But when I place the query in a job, it fails.

Here is the setting of my linked server

[image: setting]

Error

[image: error]
[image]

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: @Harsh uploaded error screenshots

Comment: that's not very helpful as I don't see the error message details. Could you please expand one of the rows and paste screenshot here?

Comment: Make Job Owner `sa` and it will work.

Comment: @lad2025 sa is already job owner

Comment: @Harsh uploaded error from logs

Comment: @PhilipMorris Change also linked server to use `Be made using current security context`

Comment: @lad2025 put in answer and I will accept. did the trick =)

Comment: @PhilipMorris My answer was edited, see last line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read [SQL Server Agent job fails when the job uses a linked server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811031).

> WORKAROUND To work around this problem, use one of the following
>   methods:
>
> Method 1
>
> **Make the system administrator the owner of the job**.
>
> Method2:
>
> Use mapped security context for the linked server and modify the job
>   to run as OSQL.
>
> To set the mapped security context for the linked server: Right-click
>   the linked server, and then click Properties. Click the Security tab.
>   Select either of the following options. Be made using the login's
>   current security context Be made using this security context To modify
>   the job to run as OSQL: Right-click the job, and then click
>   Properties. In the Steps tab, click the Step Name that you want to
>   edit, and then click Edit. On the General tab of the Edit Job Step
>   dialog box, click Operating System Command (CmdExec) in the Type list.
>   In the Command text box, type osql –E –Q “Exec storedProcedure”. In the Edit
>   Job Step dialog box, click OK. In the Properties dialog box, click OK.

In linked server definition tick:
`Be made using the login's current security context`

Comment: The link is defunct

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue, And after changing user permissions etc etc etc, I found this article and instead of using "Be made using the login's current security context" i used "Be made using this security context" and i specified the account and password which solved the issue. So the issue isnt with SQL jobs or my procedure it was in actual fact my linked server. Even though the link server did work... When calling a linked server within a SQL job the linked server had to have the account details specifically specified.