# No insert happens on linked server Express version when Agent Job activates stored procedure from linked Enterprise version server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SSMS with linked servers. Have stored procedure in Express version that performs a table insert. When the stored procedure is run locally, the table insert works.

When I run an Agent Job executing the stored procedure from the linked Enterprise version, the table insert does not happen. Linked servers are set up properly - I have all permissions turned on for both target table and stored procedures.

Comment: Is there anything visible in the [SQL Server Agent Error Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-error-log?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Nope.  Everything acts/reports like it ran perfectly - but the insert doesn't happen when run from the job.

Comment: Any difference when running the SP from the remote server, but directly from SSMS rather than from an agent job?

Comment: I have tried exec via SSMS query window on remote server and get the same result (no insert on target table).  It seems to be a property of the Express version.  I have another location that is Enterprise-to-Enterprise version and have no problem.

Comment: Can you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32477446/243373) and the answers to that question, to see if that sheds any light on your issue?